# who will tack more time complexity or time

Tags: java

I am working one java project . I am wondering

```
if (a) {
  // ...
} else if (b) {
  // ...
} else if (c) {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
if (a) {
  // ...
}
if (b) {
  // ...
}
if (c) {
  // ...
}
```

//I m sending 10 parameter like this which is the fast way problem of above code in else if I send last parameter it will check all then it will go last. so which is fast  which is slow

Comment: `else if` is generally faster since it avoids an extra check (unless you have an early return). But it has nothing to do with time complexity.

Comment: Both are really ugly. I'd go for option 3.

Comment: You wouldn't really indent your code like that, would you?

Comment: They are different, in general: in case 1, only one block is executed; in case 2, all blocks for which the condition is true are executed (assuming execution completes normally in each block).

Answer (score 3):

The *real* answer here is: unless you identified a **real** performance 
problem; you do not worry about "performance" issues within your code.

Meaning: you did some profiling and found that a certain piece of code that is called **many** millions of time during a short period of time takes "too much" time. Then you would probably start by writing small examples, trying to do reasonable [benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) to enhance your solution to meet some "target" performance.

But be assured that the difference between switch/if/if-else is in the range of nano-seconds; and you have no idea what the just-in-time-compiler is doing to your code anyway. To the contrary: the JIT is great about optimizing "normal, ordinary" code. When you start to be "clever" and "optimize" on the java source code level; chances are that you make it **harder** for the JIT to deal with your code. So, in the end; your java code looks "faster"; but the *real* execution time is worse than before.

Thus: you **focus** on writing code that is **readable**. And alone the fact that you talk about "10 parameters" that need to be treated is **bad practice**.

Long story short: focus on **good** design; for example based on [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles (of course avoiding real performance pitfalls). That will allow you to **change** your implementation later on; in case you are running into *real* performance issues.

As of now, you are wasting your energy on the wrong topic.

Answer (score 0):

Normally performance goes in order of:

- `switch` statement
- Lookup table via array or dictionary structure
- Chained `if`, `else if`
- Pile of independent `if` statements.

The `switch` is ideal if you can swing it, that can be optimized more aggressively. The series of independent `if` statements is the worst performer, each of those *must* be evaluated. Your `else if` version can perform better *if* you order them correctly and avoid doing expensive but infrequently exercised branches first.

Answer (score 0):

You worry time execution about 10 `if else if` or `if` statements ? 
If you have not noticed any concrete problems with time execution about them you should not even consider them. These are very very very lightweight instructions.

1) Two shown codes doesn't perform the same thing.
With `if else if`, the statements are related. So as soon as one condition is true, the following `else if` statements are not executed.
With a series `if`, it is not the case as statements are not coupled.

So you could have a distinct behavior according to the one or the second one way.

2) Clearly both solutions are not readable and error prone.

Rather worry about readability and maintainability of the code.
Having 10 parameters in a method and testing them in this way is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [GhostCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42434326/3788176), the most important thing is to write readable code. Once I formatted your code, it became a lot more apparent that your two approaches have different semantics:

1. In the first approach, only one of those blocks is executed. It doesn't matter if `b` is true when `a` is true: only the block associated with the `a` condition is executed.

   Moreover, if `b` is actually an expression with side effects (like an assignment or a call to a method with side effects), `b` is never evaluated, so that side effect doesn't happen.
2. In the second approach, all blocks are executed. If  both `a` and `b` are true, both of their associated blocks are executed.

So, you need to pick the one with the more appropriate behavior.

For example, given:

```
boolean a() { System.out.println("a()"); return true; }
boolean b() { System.out.println("b()"); return true; }
```

Code using approach 1:

```
if (a()) {
  /* ... */
} else if (b()) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Output:

```
a()
```

Code using approach 2:

```
if (a()) {
  /* ... */
}
if (b()) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Output:

```
a()
b()
```